# Recover deleted log files

Tags: files, data-recovery

I know that Ubuntu saves logs and rotates them overwriting older `syslog.gz` files.

Is it possible to recover overwritten logs? Perhaps with a specific software.

Answer (score 1):

Once a file is overwritten, it is lost.
What you can do is to adapt the logrotation settings to hold more occurence of the logs you are interested to.

For log files generated by the `syslogd` process (I'm not speaking here of `rsyslog` or `syslog-ng` that I'm not using), the logrotation is done by a specific script installed together with the `sysklogd` package); By default the script is `/etc/cron.daily/sysklogd`. It use the command `savelog` to rotate all the logs created by syslog.

If you need to keep more archived logs, update the line looking like :

`savelog -g adm -m 640 -u ${USER} -c 7 $LOG >/dev/null`

The number after the -c is the number of cycle, so the number of log archived in this case will be 7. (one per day as the script is run daily).

Comment: Remark: for other log files, not generated by syslog, the process `logrotate` will manage the log rotation.

Comment: Unless it is on a backup ;-)